# UIView removeFromSuperview is calling didMoveToSuperview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I don't understand why UIView's `removeFromSuperview` is calling `didMoveToSuperview`.

I would think that `didMoveToSuperview` is only called when a view is added to a view. Could anyone explain it why `removeFromSuperview` is calling `didMoveToSuperview`?

Here is what I am doing in `removeFromSuperview`:

```
public override func removeFromSuperview() {

    clearDelegates()

    chaosPad?.removeFromSuperview()
    brushSliders?.removeFromSuperview()
    moodSlider?.removeFromSuperview()
    brushShapeMenu?.removeFromSuperview()
    moodMenu?.removeFromSuperview()
    gravityMenu?.removeFromSuperview()
    rotationMenu?.removeFromSuperview()

    menuGroups = []
    centerButtons = []
    scrollMenuItems = []
    menu?.removeFromSuperview()
    menu = nil

    super.removeFromSuperview()
}

func clearDelegates() {
    chaosPad?.delegate = nil
    viewController = nil
}
```

Here is the call stack showing how `didMoveToSuperview` is called:

```
#0  0x0000000110f39708 in specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt) -> () ()
#1  0x000000010b9cb960 in TDTOilistMenuPainting.configureFrames() -> () at /FastDev/TDTPhotoLib/Oilist/Classes/TDTOilistMenuPainting.swift:161
#2  0x000000010b9cb83e in TDTOilistMenuPainting.didMoveToSuperview() -> () at /FastDev/TDTPhotoLib/Oilist/Classes/TDTOilistMenuPainting.swift:146
#3  0x000000010b9cb872 in @objc TDTOilistMenuPainting.didMoveToSuperview() -> () ()
#4  0x000000010f5d1db5 in __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke ()
#5  0x000000010dc87c60 in -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] ()
#6  0x000000010f5d19b1 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] ()
#7  0x000000010f5cf610 in __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview ()
#8  0x000000010f5cf107 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] ()
#9  0x000000010b9c9aba in TDTOilistMenuPainting.removeFromSuperview() -> () at /FastDev/TDTPhotoLib/Oilist/Classes/TDTOilistMenuPainting.swift:73
#10 0x000000010ba6d269 in TDTPaintingViewController.(navigationController(UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation : UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController : UIViewController, toViewController : UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?).(closure #2) at /FastDev/TDTPhotoLib/Oilist/Classes/TDTPaintingViewController.swift:2706
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is normal behavior. `didMoveToSuperview` is called whenever a view's superview changes, even if it changes to `nil`. You can check to see if the superview is nil or not inside that method to determine if it was added to or removed from its superview, like:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    if let superview = self.superview {
        // the view was added as a subview to superview
    }
    else {
        // the view was removed from its superview
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I am surprised it is called.

Comment: Yeah, it's a weirdly-named method, for sure. I feel like Apple should have named it `superviewDidChange` or something like that.

Comment: I completely agree!

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler Surprisingly, the [ documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622433-didmovetosuperview) even already describes it that way: _"Tells the view that its superview changed."_